# GridView Adapter not working with Orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview, android-orientation

I have been learning how to use GridView in android. I written a sample class which uses a fragment to load the data in a grid view. I am able to load the details in grid view properly but whenever i change the orientation, my grid view becomes empty.

PS : i was reading on internet about **android:configChanges**, i dont want to use that.

Here is my code:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // find the fragment on activity restarts
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("my-frag");

        // create the fragment and data the first time
        if (fragment == null) {
            // add the fragment
            fragment = new MyFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new MyFragment(), "my-frag").commit();
        } else {
            // load the data from the results
            fragment.loadData();
        }
    }

}
```

**Fragment Class**

```
/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    public MyFragment() {
    }

    private GridView resultGridView;
    private MyAdapter myAdapter;

    private String[] urls = new String[]{"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/38e4dbce6996ba5d73c56bee4297d385?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1", "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/38e4dbce6996ba5d73c56bee4297d385?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1", "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/38e4dbce6996ba5d73c56bee4297d385?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Retain this fragment across configuration changes.
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        resultGridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid);

        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), urls);
        resultGridView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        return view;
    }

    public void loadData() {
        resultGridView.invalidateViews();
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

**Adapter Class**

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private final LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    private String[] urls;

    public MyAdapter(final Context context, String[] urls) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.urls = urls;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return urls.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return urls[i];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder vh;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            vh = new ViewHolder();
            vh.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            convertView.setTag(vh);
        } else {
            vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Picasso.with(context).load(urls[position]).into(vh.imageView);
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are changing orientation to horizontal??

Comment: both horizontal and vertical.. i just want it to work in both scenarios.

Comment: but gridview has a default orientation vertical. what about that??

Comment: that remains in both cases.. i dont want to change the way grid view works.. it will always scroll in vertical manner. I am only changing the orientation of device to portrait/landscape.

Comment: means it working fine in portrait and you facing exception when you change it to landscape??

Comment: yes, and also if i go back to portrait after landscape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle) ?

You can try by adding a method getUrls() and setUrls to the adapter:

```
public void getURLs(){
    return urls;
}
public void setURLs(String[] urls){
    this.urls = urls;
}
```

Then you add the following lines to the fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mData = savedInstanceState.getStringArray("urls");
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putStringArray("urls", (getListAdapter().getURLs()));
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    myAdapter.setUrls(mData);
    loadData()
}
```

In addition, you should follow the Android code style guidelines: https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html

Comment: Do you manage to retrieve the data back ? is it still emtpy? Are you sure you perform  myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after setting back the urls?

Comment: yes, i am able to get the data back and also calling notifydatasetchanged() but i think as data is not changing so the call to notifyDataSetChanged() is not doing anything at all

Comment: Then you'll have to re instantiate the adapter in OnViewCreated, but very strange...

Comment: made it work.. the problem was that i was using setRetainInstance and your solution also.. and because of it was not working. i removed the "setRetainInstance" and it started working.

Comment: @AndroidN00b oh yeah, sorry.. i should have mentioned it.